# Let $D$ be a bounded domain (open connected) in $ \mathbb C$ and assume that complement of $D$ is connected.Then show that $\partial D$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

I am trying to prove the following famous result in Point Set Topology.

> Let $D$ be a bounded domain (open connected) in $ \mathbb C$ and assume that complement of $D$ is connected. Then show that  $\partial D$ is connected.

I know there are proofs of this result using Fundamental Group and Algebraic Topology but I don't know much Algebraic Topology so I am trying to prove this result using Elementary Topology only.
I am planning to use following basic result of Point Set Topology:

> Let $(K_i)_{i\in I}$ be an indexed family of decreasing, connected, compact sets in a Topological space X. Then $B = \bigcap_i K_i$ is connected.

I defined  $K_n$= {$ z \in D : dist (z, \partial D) \leq \frac{1}{n}$}. Now as distance is a continuous function therefore each $K_n$ is compact and also $K_n$ is a decreasing sequence. Furthermore, $ \bigcap K_i$=$\partial D$. So I think now its enough to show that each $K_i$ is connected. I personally believe that each $K_i$ is path connected, but I am unable to prove this. Feel free to scold me If I am doing something wrong here. Please help with my idea or give some different proof using elementary topology only!

Comment: Would a proof with [Jordan's Curve Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) be enough? It can be proved using only elementary topology, although that proof is quite long and notation-heavy...

Comment: Dear @A.P. although i would like to complete my proof but I am curious to see a proof  by Jordan's theorem too.Can you please sketch?Regards,

Comment: First, note that $\Bbb{C}$ has the same topology as $\Bbb{R}^2$. Since $D$ is bounded (with non-empty interior) its border is a union of closed curves. In particular, if $\partial D$ isn't connected it contains at least two distinct simple closed curves. By Jordan's Curve Theorem this means that $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \partial D = D \cup D^c$ has at least three connected components. But that's absurd because both $D$ and $D^c$ are connected by hypothesis.

Comment: @A.P.Ah.Thank you,but the Proof of Jordan Curve theorem in Wikipedia is via Algebraic Topology.Can you give some reference for topological proof?

Comment: @A.P. Sorry..why do u say that border of $D$ is union of closed curves?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the proof in [Kosniowski's book](https://editorialdinosaurio.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/79356060-a-first-course-in-algebraic-topology-c-kosniowski.pdf) doesn't use algebraic topology, despite being titled "A first course in algebraic topology".

Comment: Humm... you are right, it is not necessarily a union of closed curves. Most importantly, it may not contain two Jordan curves, e.g. if $D$ is the open unit disk minus a point. On the other hand, it may be possible to fix the proof by excluding a couple of cases.

Comment: My first thought was to use paths to approximate the boundary. However, it looks like the the boundary need not be path connected. The counter-example isn't too bad. Imagine a square, but the top and bottom lines are replaced with topologists's sine curves. The interior of this region is open and connected.

Comment: Your sets $K_i$ are not necessarily connected, imagine an open torus (donut). The boundary is two concentric rings, and the set of all points in the torus within $1/n$ of the boundary is two thin disconnected rings (for $1/n$ sufficiently small).

Comment: @Michael: in that case the complement of $D$ is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let us continue your approach, assuming by contradiction that $K_n$ is not connected for some $n$. Cover $K_{4n}$ with finitely many open balls of radius $1/(4n)$ and take a connected component $C$ of the union of these balls. Note that this union $B$ is not connected, since a descomposition of $K_n$ yields a decomposition of $K_{4n}$ and of $B$.

Let $E_1$ be the connected component of $\partial C$, which is a closed Jordan curve. Then 
$E_1$ lies entirely in $D$ or entirely in $\bar D^c$. By the Jordan curve theorem, we have a disjoint union $\Bbb{C}=E_1\cup A_1\cup A_2$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open. Each of the open sets $A_1,A_2$ contains points of $\partial D$, so each contains
points of $D$ and of $D^c$. Hence, if $E_1\subset D$, then $D^c$ is not connected, and if 
$E_1\subset \bar D^c$, then $D$ is not connected.

This contradiction shows that $\partial D$ is connected.

If you want to avoid using the Jordan curve theorem, you have to prove a weak version of it, for curves that are part of the boundary of a union of balls of the same radius.

$\bf{Theorem}$ (weak Jordan curve theorem for boundaries of union of balls): Assume you have a covering of the plane by $\varepsilon$ balls, such that two of them intersect if and only if their centers can be connected by a straight line that intersects no other ball of the covering.  Take $B$ to be the union of a finite number of this balls. Then there is a connected component of $\partial B$, such that we have a disjoint union $\Bbb{R}^2= A_1\cup A_2\cup \partial B$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open, and $B\subset A_1$.

Comment: Sorry..I don't really understand the idea of your proof.How do you think of such a proof?

Comment: The idea is the following: Assume $\partial D$ is disconnected, cover a connected component by finitely many $\varepsilon$-balls, apply the jordan curve theorem to a connected component of the boundary of a union of such balls.

Comment: Why $E_1$  lies entirely in $D$ or entirely in $\bar D ^c$?

Comment: $E_1$ is a curve that consiste of finitely many arc of circles and the distance to $\partial D$ is at least $1/4n$, so it cannot contain points of both $D$ and $D^c$.

Comment: In that case you would have a parameterization $\gamma$ of $E_1$ and $\gamma(t_0)\in \partial D$, where $t_0= inf\{ t,\gamma(t)\in D\}$ if $\gamma(0)\in D^c$, and $t_0=sup\{t, \gamma(t)\in D^c\}$ if $\gamma(0)\in D$.